# Maven : Unable to get Property Value from Proprties file

Tags: java, maven, properties, maven-3

I'm a newbee in apache Maven. When i try to read the values from the properties file, it's not picking the value. I already seen all the previously asked questions in SO. But no luck with that. This is my property file.

```
nameofmayil=mayilsamy
```

This is the **pom.xml**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.mayil</groupId>
  <artifactId>mayil-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>mayil-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>    
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
      </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://127.0.0.1/svn/my-project</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://127.0.0.1/svn/my-project</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
    <url>http://127.0.0.1/websvn/my-project</url>
  </scm>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                  <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
                  <executions>
                    <!-- Associate the read-project-properties goal with the initialize phase, to read the properties file. -->
                    <execution>
                      <phase>initialize</phase>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <configuration>
                        <files>
                          <file>${basedir}/buildNumber.properties</file>
                          <file>${basedir}/mayil.properties</file>
                        </files>
                        <quite>false</quite>
                      </configuration>
                    </execution>
                  </executions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>1.6</version>
                  <executions>
                    <execution>
                      <phase>validate</phase>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <configuration>
                        <target>
                          <echo>Displaying value of properties</echo>
                          <echo>${nameofmayil}</echo>
                        </target>
                      </configuration>
                    </execution>
                  </executions>
                </plugin>
          </plugins>
      </build>
</project>
```

The property file is loaded properly, i checked with that.

Comment: Could you show build log? What command do you use to run build?

Comment: Ok, what output do you get from running `mvn install`? Please add this info to question.

Comment: run a write-project-properties in the validate phase, then you will be able to see all the properties that are set. I can't really remember how this plugin works but it might be setting some prefix on the property name

Answer (score 2):

The POM shown has the `properties-maven-plugin` execution bound to the `initialize` phase, and the antrun plugin goal displaying the properties bound to the `validate` phase.  `initialize` comes after `validate` (per the Maven [lifecycle docs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)) which is why you're not seeing the results you want.  You may fix in a couple of ways:

- bind the `properties-maven-plugin` goal to the `validate` phase *OR*
- bind the `maven-antrun-plugin` goal to the `initialize` phase

Both of the above have goals bound to the same phase.  This is fine, as long as the goals are listed in the POM in the order you want them to execute.  If you want them bound to distinct phases, perform both steps.